# Better to learn with LAMP/Django or more basic building blocks?

Tags: lamp, django, learning

I'm looking to pick up basic web development by working through Programming Python's internet scripting chapters (especially the server-side scripting).

Question: when I'm attempting to learn the basics of being a webmaster, should I jump into a full LAMP (with Python instead of PHP)/Django implementation? Or do you recommend I learn the basics with simpler pieces (e.g. Python web-server pieces like CGIHTTPServer/ BaseHTTPServer, sqlite3, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect Django would be a great place to start, especially with the [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/) which is where I cut my teeth on using Python server side.  I was very familiar with PHP and Drupal as well as a little Perl and Ruby on Rails for writing web apps beforehand but Django is extremely pleasant to use and tends to emphasize best practices.

Once you've built something by all means go back and dig deeper into the basics. Django's also loosely coupled, so while it provides most everything you should need it's easy enough to replace components or hand-roll your own if it ever becomes necessary.

For learning purposes keep it nice and simple using sqlite3 and the built in Django webserver.  Best of luck hope you have a blast :)

Answer (score 3):

LAMP is a lot to take on, if your focus is Python, you might want to try **CherryPy**.

"CherryPy is an object-oriented web application framework using the Python programming language. It is designed for rapid development of web applications by wrapping the HTTP protocol, CherryPy is the web server itself, and has a very small foot print."

**CherryPy official documentation**
http://cherrypy.org/wiki/TableOfContents

**CherryPy Tutorial**
http://cherrypy.org/wiki/CherryPyTutorial

**Also, you might find these question of use too:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988/how-to-learn-python